# Displaying Push Notification Badges Without Notification Service Extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, onesignal

The origin of my problem is that I am not able to test push messages on real devices because of a problem that seems to be an Xcode bug, but this is not the subject now. I just added this to answer why I can't test my implementation normally.

So I have the push notifications implemented in my iOS app with the OneSignal SDK. Based on their [setup guide](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-setup) they recommend to create a `"Notification Service Extension"` which also caused issues (with the provisioning profile) in my app, that I couldn't fix yet. Therefore I decided to skip adding the extension that means I won't be able to use some specific features, like sending images and altering the badges. I don't care about sending images, but badges would be a must.

My question is that adding a `"Notification Service Extension"` is really required to manipulate the badges for iOS 11/12/13? My goal is to just simply display `"1"` on the app icon when the client receives a push message. 2-3 years ago when I previously implemented push notifications I didn't need any magic except the below line:

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{


    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1]

}
```

Did this change? Or will it display a badge with the number of `1` and I don't have to be afraid about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ios13 doesn't allow PushKit for non VOIP scenarios. you will have to add a NSE as they advertise. It isnt just for images anymore.

Comment: So if I want to make it work under ios 13 I have to do it from the App Delegate and for ios 13 I need the extension? Right?

Comment: Yeah you have to have a notification service extension. There are tutorials for it. It is a bit cumbersome but not too hard. There is nothing in appdelegate involved